# Oracle partitioning scenario with primary key absolutely required

Tags: oracle, partitioning, primary-key

Is there any partitioning scenario in which the partitioned table is absolutely required to have primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [reference partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/vldbg/partition-concepts.html#GUID-54D18B18-6838-4115-9389-E1FB0D20A8CA) requires a primary key on the parent table.

> Reference partitioning enables the partitioning of two tables that are
>   related to one another by referential constraints.
>
> The partitioning key is resolved through an existing parent-child
>   relationship, enforced by enabled and active primary key and foreign
>   key constraints.

If you try to do this with a unique key instead of a primary key, you will get this error:

```
ORA-02268: referenced table does not have a primary key
```

Comment: @M.Dawid You can partition index-organized tables too. Index-organized tables must have a primary key, but that is the requirement of the IOT, not partitioning.